# Swift: Collection of generic collections

Tags: swift, generics

I have a baseclass `ItemBase` and a class `CollectionBase` with items of type `ItemBase`.

I derive two classes from this `ItemBase` - `PersonItem` and `AnimalItem`.

I derive two classes from `CollectionBase` with the appropriate items - `PersonCollection` and `AnimalCollection`.

And then I create an array of type `CollectionBase`-`ItemBase`.

Now I want append the `PersonCollection` and `AnimalCollection` to the array, but I get the following Error:

> "Cannot assign value of type 'PersonCollection' to type
>   'DataCollection"

How can I define the collection-array, that I can append items based on `CollectionBase`-`ItemBase`?

```
class ItemBase {
}

class CollectionBase<T: ItemBase> {
  var Items = [T]()
}

class PersonItem: ItemBase {
}

class PersonCollection: CollectionBase<PersonItem> {
}

class AnimalItem: ItemBase {
}

class AnimalCollection: CollectionBase<AnimalItem> {
}

var collection = [CollectionBase<ItemBase>]()

// Error: Cannot assign value of type 'PersonCollection' to type 'DataCollection<ItemBase>
collection.append(PersonCollection())
// Error: Cannot assign value of type 'AnimalCollection' to type 'DataCollection<ItemBase>
collection.append(AnimalCollection())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your example contains some contradictary statements about the type system that the compiler (correctly) cannot accept.

For that 'aha moment', read up on [variance and contravariance on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)).  Otherwise, continue reading.

---

The reason your example fails here, is that

```
var collection = [CollectionBase<ItemBase>]()
```

defines an array of classes to which you can access and update the `Items` member property with items of class ItemBase.

Then you try to append an array element `PersonCollection()` which violates this requirement - it does not allow adding an ItemBase to it's Items member.

---

Secondly, because

> PersonCollection inherits from ItemBase

you are taking as read that the following is true:

> SomeGeneric<PersonCollection> inherits from SomeGeneric<ItemBase>

while this may make perfect sense to you, there is nothing in the swift language that makes it so.

You might reasonably point out here that **the swift collection classes seem to manage this OK** - as follows:

```
class ItemBase {
}

class PersonItem: ItemBase {
}

class AnimalItem: ItemBase {
}

var collection = [Array<ItemBase>]()

collection.append([PersonItem]())
```

Which it does, but unfortunately it does this because the swift language has special rules for the built-in collection types such as `Array`.  [As far as I know](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5056) you couldn't independently implement Array using only swift code.

---

So how to handle this?

Until you resolve the above inconsistencies in your design, you cannot.  However, I assume these features are just artefacts of how you approached the problem given the language you have.

You could use swift's built-in Array class.

Or you can define a different inheritance hierarchy that isn't generic at the base:

For example - use a protocol (or a class) at the base, that definitely works on ItemBase objects (has no associated type requirement).

```
protocol ItemCollection {
    var items:[ItemBase] { get }
}

class ThingCollection<Thing:ItemBase>:ItemCollection {
    var things:[Thing] = []
    var items:[ItemBase] {
        return things
    }
}

typealias PersonCollection = ThingCollection<PersonItem>


var itemCollection:[ItemCollection] = []

itemCollection.append(PersonCollection())
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the additional indirection? What is wrong with:

```
class ItemBase {
}

class PersonItem: ItemBase {
}

class AnimalItem: ItemBase {
}

var collection = [ItemBase]()
collection.append(PersonItem())
collection.append(AnimalItem())
```

Or:

```
class ItemBase {
}

class PersonItem: ItemBase {
}

class AnimalItem: ItemBase {
}

var collection = [[ItemBase]]()
collection.append([PersonItem]())
```

What is also possible:

```
class ItemBase {
}

class PersonItem: ItemBase {
}

class AnimalItem: ItemBase {
}

class CollectionBase<T: ItemBase> {
    var Items = [T]()
}

class PersonCollection: CollectionBase<PersonItem> {
}

class AnimalCollection: CollectionBase<AnimalItem> {
}

let personCollection = PersonCollection()
personCollection.Items.append(PersonItem())
```

But I think the additional indirection you want is not possible in Swift. You can solve it, but are loosing the strict type safety:

```
var collection = [AnyObject]()
collection.append(PersonCollection())
collection.append(AnimalCollection())

if collection[0] is PersonCollection {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: In the example the CollectionBase class is empty, but the class has much more functionality. So I need it in this way.

Comment: I added an additional variant to the answer.

Comment: Thanks Darko, but I need the PersonCollection and AnimalCollection in one collection ... i also think, that it is not possible. I searched the last days for a solution and this post is my last hope.

Comment: Thats not a solution, because i need the type safety CollectionBase<ItemBase> type in other functions.

Comment: Even this is not possible: collection.append(CollectionBase<PersonItem>()); That is also one indirection to much for the compiler.